# Changing wm_concat to other solution

Tags: plsql, listagg, wm-concat

I have this code, using wm_concat:

```
SELECT ... 
       wm_concat(distinct pori.inma_symbol ||' '|| pori.inma_nazwa|| '-' || pori.ilosc ||pori.JDMR_BAZOWA_NAZWA) as INDEKS,...
FROM ... pord
INNER JOIN ... maga
ON ...
inner join ... pori
on ...
where ... to_char(sysdate-1,'YYYY-MM_DD') AND to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM_DD')
and ... NOT LIKE 'ZZ'  AND  p... NOT LIKE 'CZ'
group by ...
ORDER BY ...
```

listagg does not support a distinct keyword, and I do not have Idea, how easy do this.
Help :)

Comment: What version of Oracle database are you using? If you want to use listagg with distinct values, just do the distinct in a subquery before calling listagg.

Comment: 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0
, but, there is no subquery, i understand, I must do this?

Comment: that's right, 12c supports listagg.